# Create two new polygons inside existing polygon hole

Tags: qgis, geoprocessing, editing, polygon-creation

I would like to create new polygon inside the existing polygon.
It does not means donuts polygon.

I would like to have two polygon without overlapping.

I can create if I don't check "Avoid intersection" from snapping option.
Unfortunately, there is overlapping new polygon and existing polygon.

It must not have overlapping area.

Comment: If I explain very simply, I would like to create double ring polygon without overlapping. I have already create external ring polygon. I don't know how to create internal ring polygon.

Comment: Could you just use two polygon layers instead of one? What sort of data are you trying to create polygons from?

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to do it in my mind. If you have many **complicated polygons**:

1. create layer with outer polygons
2. create layer with inner polygons
3. use *Vector / Geoprocessing Tools / Difference* to make holes in outer polygons
4. merge layer from step 3 with layer from step 2 - *Vector / Data management Tools / Merge shapefiles to one*

Second option if you have few **simple polygons**:

1. create outer polygon
2. create hole in polygon (*Edit / Add Ring*)
3. set snapping (*Settings / Snapping Options...*)
4. create inner polygon by snapping to inner nodes (hole/ring) of outer polygon

Comment: I have complicated polygons. but, second option is better for me because of simple.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Buffer command, with negative value i.e. -50.
Operating in a UTM projection is more intuitive when using this type of action.

Comment: Internal ring is not the same shape of outer ring. anyway, thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if you might prefer to create your polygons with lines and then polygonise them with the Polygonizer plug-in? See the attached images (and perhaps also have a look at http://confound.me.uk/maps/ppv4.pdf). N.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I have already polygon not polyline. If I start from polyline, I will follow your suggestion.

Comment: It is possible to convert polygons to lines in QGIS. N.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you, you have a main polygon which includes many polygons that are close.
a) first draw the main polygon

[image]

b)Define a ring that surround all inner polygons (I am asuuming this is your case)

[image]

c) Make sure you have defined the snapping options as this:

[image]

d) Draw the first inner polygon in the ring:

[image]

notice since you defined that there must not be intersection of new polygons the inner polygon is correctly created.

[image]

e) Define the same way the remaining polygons

[image]

[image]

If the above description fits your case, that should do it.

Hope it helps

Gerardo